# Need to fix a specific owner on a linux folder which should not change

Tags: permissions, acl

I have a folder on my linux machine called 'fileduploaddata' which has owner 'leadangel:la-editor', whenever I create any directory or file inside fileuploaddata folder the owner get changed from leadangel to root.

I want that leadangel owner should always fixed on 'fileuploaddata' folder and it should not change when we create any file inside it.

**I have tried:-**

sudo chmod -R u+s

[image]

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? We do not use root. Stop using root and the system will not create files as root. We use "sudo".  Use user fileuploaddata if you need to create files for fileuploaddata. Whenever you use another user you need to do a `sudo chown {user}:{group}`  on the file that needs it. "I have tried:- sudo chmod -R u+s"  not while using root as in the image I would hope...

Comment: This is not possible and will not be implemented for security reasons: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99096/524752 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27374/524752 If you want to give access to the leadangel, you can use default acls, but seeing the "+" in your screenshot, you might have already explored that alternative